# .NET Framework 4.0.3 as a Prerequisite in ClickOnce package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-4.0, clickonce, visual-studio-2015

I have an application that targets .NET 4.0 packaged as a ClickOnce deployment—built with VS 2015 Enterprise. It will install just fine with only 4.0 installed, but in testing I've found that the application requires update 4.0.3 ([KB2600211](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2600211)) in order to work correctly.

How do I make this update a prerequisite for installing the software? It doesn't appear to be an option:
[image: Prerequisites]

Comment: Have you tried targeting 4.5? I'm thinking 4.5 would include 4.0.3

Comment: @PhilSattele I can't. Support for Windows XP is a fixed requirement for this project, and Windows XP doesn't support .NET 4.5. Unfortunately it seems 4.0.3 is the only version that is supported on all the required operating systems *and* has the features to make the software run correctly.

Comment: what about .NET framework 4 and Update for .NET framework 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time I haven't really found a solution, but I've come up with this rather kludgy workaround. Basically, I found the section of app startup code that throws an error on systems that don't have this update, and wrapped it in special error handling code. In that error handler, I simply do a manual check on the current runtime version and if it fails, I present the user with a specific error message.

```
private static string InvalidFxVerMessage = 
    "This application requires .NET Framework v{0} or later but has detected that your system is running v{1}.\n\n" +
    "Please contact your system administrator to install the following components: \n" +
    "\u2003\u2022 Update 4.0.3 for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 – Runtime Update (KB2600211)"

private void InitializeApp()
{
    try
    {
        // Run some code that throws an exception if update 4.0.3 is not installed.
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        var envVers = Environment.Version;
        var reqVers = new Version(4, 0, 30319, 551);
        if (envVers < reqVers)
        {
            var msg = string.Format(InvalidFxVerMessage, reqVers, envVers);
            MessageBox.Show(
                msg,
                "Unsupported Framework Version",
                MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Error);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

It's not great and I'd love to find a better solution, but this at least tells the user exactly what went wrong and gives them an indication of how to fix it.